# VS2010 and expression blend 3

Tags: visual-studio-2010, expression-blend

VS2010 is installed in my machine and when we create wpf project from VS2010 IDE then can we open that wpf project from expression blend 3  & restyle the control and get back to VS2010 for coding. so i just want to know Expression blend 3 is compatible for VS2010 or VS2008?
please discuss. thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your xaml would get updated with changes from Expression blend 3. And they work perfectly fine.